# service not defined when precompiling a web app with AJAX-enabled WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, wcf, asp.net-ajax

I created a web application in which one .aspx page calls an AJAX-enabled WCF service (created with Visual Studio 2008 Add New Item -> AJAX-enabled WCF Service).

when I test the application in Visual Studio, it works and the page can call the service from Javascript but when I "publish" (code precompilation using Visual Studio) it to the local IIS Server, I get an error :

```
"service ThunServ is undefined" in my .html page.
```

I've been spending quite a time to solve this problem but to no avail.

Omar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you managed to resolve the issue.

This problem also occur when you try to access the page using HTTPS.

All you need to do is create a  in Web.config and set the security mode to Transport that means transport-level security is used with HTTP requests.

example:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="AjaxBinding">
      <security mode="Transport"></security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

in endpoint configuration of your services section add:

```
bindingConfiguration="AjaxBinding"
```

That should fix the problem.